# Ajax Tool Kit is not working using VS 2013

Tags: ajax, visual-studio-2013

Ajax Tool Kit is not working using master page, but working perfectly without using master pages. I am trying this since one week still not able to to find solution.

Below is the master page html code:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
```

I have added script manager into the master page.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <Scripts>

            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />

        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>
```

Content page html code:

```
 <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

Added script into content page:

```
  <asp:ScriptManagerProxy runat="server" />
```

I am using toolkitmanger for Calender extender below is html design:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt_Dispdate" runat="server" Style="width: 50%" CssClass="form-control"  AutoPostBack="True" OnTextChanged="txt_Dispdate_TextChanged"
                                   ></asp:TextBox>

<cc1:calendarextender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txt_Dispdate"
                              OnClientDateSelectionChanged="CheckForPastDate"  Enabled="True" Format="MM/dd/yyyy"></cc1:calendarextender>
```

Web.config control and assemblies code:

```
     <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  </assemblies>

 <controls>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt" />
    <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />

  </controls>
```

When I will click in textbox nothing calendar is showing. I also tried below example.
https://timscyclingblog.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/ajaxcontroltoolkit-version-7-0123-with-net-4-5/

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, I forgot to put the CheckForPastDate JavaScript Function into Master page. That's why calendar is not showing.

Thank you